# MySQL inserting blank row, cant figure out why, no errors

Tags: php, mysql

My website provides services and access is granted only after an account is created, which happens only after a payment is complete.

The problem I am having is with my mySQL statement below. I know there aren't any 'deal-breaking' errors within the statement itself because if I set `$usr_name = 'bob'`  for example instead of the session variable (which is what I need), it gets added to the db with no problems using the same exact mySQL query. The problem comes in when I try to set the variables to the session variables below. When I do that, a blank row gets added to the database.

You would think that the session variables don't contain anything, which would be a logical explanation to my problem, however, the echo in the code below which gets its values from session variables prints out everything as it should, so the session variables are set correctly.

I would aslo like to add that the code is written correctly for the most part and gets to the inner most if-statement upon payment completion, as it should.

also, tried adding or `die(mysql_error())` to my query, and no errors printed out.

I would really appreciate it if someone can suggest what I can do to try and solve this problem.

```
<?php

    session_start();
    //Create mysql connect variable
    $conn = mysql_connect('myhostedresource.com', 'user', 'password');

    //kill connection if error occurs
    if(!$conn){
        die('Error: Unable to connect.' . '<br>' . mysql_error());
    }

    //connect to mysql database
    mysql_select_db("stevenash", $conn);

    // PHP 4.1
    // read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
    $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
        $req .= "&$key=$value";
    }

    // post back to PayPal system to validate
    $header .= "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

    // assign posted variables to local variables
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];       


    $usr_email = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['email']);
    $usr_compname = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['compname']);
    $usr_city = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['city']);
    $usr_state = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['state']);
    $usr_phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['phone']);
    $usr_password = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['password']);
    $usr_first = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['first']);
    $usr_last = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['last']);


    $_SESSION['email'];

    if (!$fp) {
        // HTTP ERROR
    }else{
        fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
            if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
                // check the payment_status is Completed
                if($payment_status == 'Completed'){
                    $txn_id_check = mysql_query("SELECT txn_id FROM log WHERE txn_id='$txn_id'");
                    //add user to database
                    if(mysql_num_rows($txn_id_check) != 1){ //payment has not been processed yet
                        //continue processing
                        if($receiver_email=='matthayzon89@gmail.com'){
                            if($payment_amount=='1.00' && $payment_currency=='USD'){
                                //add transaction id to db
                                mysql_query("INSERT INTO log (`log_id`, `txn_id`, `email`) VALUES('','$txn_id','$payer_email')", $conn);            

                                $myString = "INSERT users (`email`, `compname`, `city`, `state`, `phone`, `password`, `first`, `last`) 
                                            VALUES('".$usr_email."','".$usr_compname."','".$usr_city."','".$usr_state."','".$usr_phone."','".$usr_password."','".$usr_first."','".$usr_last."')";
                                echo $myString;     

                                mysql_query($myString,$conn);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
                // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
                // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
                // process payment
            }
            else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
                // log for manual investigation
            }
        }
        fclose ($fp);
    }
?>
```

Comment: which query inserting blank row??

Comment: The second one mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (`id`, `email`, `compname`, `city`, `state`, `phone`, `password`, `first`, `last`) 
                                        VALUES('', '$usr_email','$usr_compname','$usr_city','$usr_state','$usr_phone','$usr_password','$usr_first','hello')",$conn);

Comment: Your query is vulnerable to SQL injection. At the very least, use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) (or if you have a choice, don't use PHP).

Comment: I am trying to get it to work first, thats my first priority, my site isn't live yet... still in testing phase, I will add mysql escape string, thanks.

Comment: @MHZ I mention it partially because it's a gaping security hole, but also because not escaping values can be the cause of errors.

Comment: Please check new code, I added mysql_real_escape_stringm though it is still adding a blank row in the db...

Comment: have you checked that every field in the `MySQL` table is properly designed?
eg. if you have an `INT` field and you're inserting a `string`, it will default the input (standard is an empty entry). **Also**, @BrendanLong put up a good point. IMO, don't even bother coming for help with a `MySQL` error when you're not even sanitizing input, thats easily the #1 cause for these errors.

Comment: Yes, I doublechecked, all fields are varchars. @jared, I updated my code if take you a look now I am sanitizing my input and it is still inserting an empty row. If I run the insert query BEFORE all the nested if statements, just the way it is now, it inserts the row perfectly. If I run the query from within all the nested if-statements (Which is where I need it to be), it inserts an empty row.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `id` in second query is `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Whenever `AUTO_INCREMENT` fields are there, don't use them in query. Also you are setting that as `''` which is incorrect.

Your query **should** be.

```
 mysql_query("
            INSERT INTO users 
            (`email`, `compname`, `city`, `state`, `phone`, `password`, `first`, `last`)
            VALUES(
           '$usr_email','$usr_compname','$usr_city','$usr_state',$usr_phone,
            '$usr_password','$usr_first','hello')",$conn);
```

### Edit 1

Also `$usr_phone` should not be in quote as phone number is Integer value...

Comment: id is AUTO_INCREMENT but that does not solve my problem, it is still adding a blank row... thanks for trying though

Comment: @MHZ : Ok, can you take query in one variable and echo that variable before mysql_query statement?? E.g. var $myString = "INSERT ...."; echo $myString and tell me what you get??

Comment: phone number is a VARCHAR string... Ex: 123-456-4567

Comment: ok, then put it in quote.. can you echo and tell me what you get??

Comment: @MHZ : Quick... I am yawning... :D

Comment: INSERT users (`email`, `compname`, `city`, `state`, `phone`, `password`, `first`, `last`) VALUES('mmfffrrr@gmail.com','west corp','nevada','AL','111-222-3333','123456','dennis','hello')

Comment: @MHZ : Query seems correct... Can you provide the table structure?

Comment: if I change the variables to strings like posted above and then run the query, it inserts perfect. On the other hand, if I store those strings in variables then run the query, it inserts a blank row... keeping this in mind, my table structure wont help... all fields are varchars... no wierd characters in the strings.

Comment: @MHZ : first query is getting executed properly??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13490/discussion-between-mhz-and-fahim-parkar)

Comment: No I did not... I added mysql_real_escape_string to my stored variables, but it did not help. I also realized that if I run the query just the way it is BEFORE all the nested if statements, it gets added correctly, and if I run the query WITHIN all the nested if-statements (which is the way it is now), then it adds a blank row...

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO log (log_id, txn_id, email) VALUES('','$txn_id','$payer_email')", $conn);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (`id`, `email`, `compname`, `city`, `state`, `phone`, `password`, `first`, `last`)
             VALUES('', '$usr_email','$usr_compname','$usr_city','$usr_state','$usr_phone','$usr_password','$usr_first','hello')",$conn);
```

Try printing out your SQL before you run it to see what it's doing:

```
$logSql = "INSERT INTO log (log_id, txn_id, email) VALUES('','$txn_id','$payer_email')";
echo $logSql;
// mysql_query($logSql, $conn);

$insertSql = "INSERT INTO users (`id`, `email`, `compname`, `city`, `state`, `phone`, `password`, `first`, `last`)
              VALUES('', '$usr_email','$usr_compname','$usr_city','$usr_state','$usr_phone','$usr_password','$usr_first','hello')";
echo $insertSql;
// mysql_query($insertSql, $conn);
```

Figure out what's wrong, and keep working backwards (adding `echo` statements) until you find the source of the problem.

Comment: @MHZ That's why I suggest the `echo` statements. They'll *show you* what's wrong, and you can move backwards until you find the real problem.

Comment: I printed out the query and variables, this is what I got (it looks correct): INSERT users (email, compname, city, state, phone, password, first, last) VALUES('mmfffrrr@gmail.com','west corp','nevada','AL','111-222-3333','123456','dennis','hello')